# VS2013 AZURE Missing Templates

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I am on Windows 7 - It is completely up to date.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

I have installed .NET AZURE SDK 2.4 (the latest)

I have restarted PC

And Yet, there are no AZURE templates when I want to make a new project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The tools are in the Azure SDK.

Problem was VS EXPRESS 2013 FOR DESKTOP does not support AZURE, you must use VS EXPRESS 2013 FOR WEB.

You can have both installed at the same time. You can actually run both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the tools for VS? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee405484.aspx